# ul li exclusive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

Imagine the situation like i have a set of crayons, and I want to be able to pick 
one up, and start drawing, but if -in the middle of the drawing- I change my mind, I still want to be able to change the crayon and pick up a different color.

So I have made a `ul` list of elements, and I want to bind on each of them an object, which has, among its methods, the ability to draw a shape.

To reach my ideal scenario, each object is exclusive, in the sense that if I click on another `li` while the previous is active (and the shape is not yet completed), I want the disable the previous `li` element and enable the current one.
But also, if I click on the same `li` while it's still active, it should simply disable the "crayon".

The objects I'm using to draw such shapes, possesses such `enable()` and `disable()` function, so I guess it's just a matter of establishing the right combination of controls...which sadly seems I'm not able to do.

Here's an example:

```
 <ul class='crayon-toolbox'>
     <li id='1' class="crayon"></li>
     <li id='2' class="crayon"></li>
     <li id='3' class="crayon"></li>
 </ul>

 $('.crayon-toolbox').on('click', function(){
    new Crayon();
 })
```

Can anyone point me out in the right direction?
It seems to me that every time I click on a `li`I should check if that `li`has been clicked, and if not so start the Crayon object...or something like that, but I'm not sure how to check when I click on another `li` (mind you I want to use only **one crayon**  at all times).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a good idea to work with an active class.
The properties of each crayon is something you can add in the data perhaps. Not sure if calling `new Crayon()` each time is performant ...
Instead I suggest to add a method inside the `Crayon` object that allows you to change it's properties.

**HTML**

```
<ul class='crayon-toolbox'>
    <li class="crayon" data-color="red"></li>
    <li class="crayon" data-color="green"></li>
    <li class="crayon" data-color="blue"></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var anyCrayon = new Crayon();

$('.crayon-toolbox').on('click', function(){
    var crayon = $(this),
        color = crayon.data('color');

    anyCrayon.setColor(color);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I gave points also to @karl-andré-gagnon since he gave a similar answer, but accepted yours since it's more complete/explanatory with the HTML/JS snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to fully understand your question, but from what I've read, you want to create a new object when you click on a crayon, but if the crayon has already been clicked, it doesn't have to create the object.

**That sound like a job for [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)!**

Basically, you simply check if the HTML node as a object in its data. In case it doesn't, you simply assign one.

```
$('.crayon-toolbox').on('click', 'li', function(){ //I've used delegation here, need to target the LI itself for the data.
    var $this = $(this);
    var my_crayon = $this.data('crayon') || new Crayon();

    $this.data('crayon', my_crayon);
});
```

Comment: exactly, should we rub eachother's backs? ^^

Comment: I could use a little back massage, what about you?

Answer (score 1):

you can just set different css for selected crayon like below:

```
$('.crayon').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
          {$(this).removeClass('selected'); 
           //if there is a code for disabling current crayon add it here
          }
   else{
          $('.crayon').removeClass('selected');
          $(this).addClass('selected');
          //if there is a code for selecting or disabling crayon add here
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already accepted as correct another answer, since it was more relevant to my question, but you part also pertains to what I asked. Thank You Sir.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding onClick event on each li